# Buoyancy script for uneven river

Tags: unity-game-engine

We are working on river game where river has uneven slopes.I want to incorporate buoyancy to moving objects.

I have tried the following script which works perfectly fine.Though it only work if water is at fixed height i.e., Y position of water is fixed.

In our case we have uneven river where river do have slopes.

So my question is how can I make buoyancy to work on my river where y position is not fixed?

Here is link to script,
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/buoyancy-script.72974/